# How do I trigger all upstream_failed task to "retry" after their parents state changed to success in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a simple example showing a DAG with two levels. When running, this dag fails because artificial bug, there is one `failed` task and one that that is `upstream_fail`.

```
bug = True 

def process1(param):
    print("process 1 running {}".format(param))
    if bug and (param == 2):
        raise Exception("failure!!")


def process2(param):
    print("process 2 running {}".format(param))


with dag:
    for i in range(10):
        task1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id="process_1_{}".format(i),
            python_callable=process1,
            op_kwargs={'param': i}
        )
        task2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id="process_2_{}".format(i),
            python_callable=process2,
            op_kwargs={'param': i},
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
            retries=2
        )
        task1 >> task2
```

Now lets assume I fixed the bug (`bug = False`) and tried to clear all failed task:

```
airflow clear -s 2001 -e 2019 --only_failed test_resubmit
```

This command clears the task `test_resubmit.process_1_2` and it will run successfully, however its downstream (i.e. `test_resubmit.process_2_2`) is still in the `upstream_failed` state. How do I trigger all upstream_failed task to "retry" after their parents state changed to success?

Answer (score 0):

The `upstream_failed` state is an end state, so it will not retry even if its dependencies are now satisfied (unlike `up_for_retry`). You'll want to pass `--downstream` so that tasks downstream of the failed tasks are also cleared.

See all options in https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#clear.

Comment: I tried --downstream, it does not work. It does not "clear" the downstream task of a failed task. I had to manually select all downstream task and clear them.